# Need Easy Way to install & configure Java JDK & Tomcat on Fedora 13/Linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, fedora, fedora12

I am trying to install Java JDK & Tomcat on my Fedora 13, however I am facing lots of issues.

I have gone through many blogs and many Stack Overflow posts, but still I am unable to configure it properly.

Info:

1. I am trying to install JAVA JDK using .rpm package as I am unable to do it using YUM repository. (You can also tell me how can i install yum repository).
2. I tried to install the JDK & tomcat but after installation, when I tried to start tomcat using startup.sh, it was giving error like:

   ```
   Using CATLINA_HOME
   Using CATLINA_BASE etc etc
   ```
3. How to find JDK path & configure JAVA_HOME path.

I know my questions are really confusing, but I need help. Links to posts of related questions would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Installing JDK on Fedora:**

1 ) Please visit sun java website to download any java jdk version you like.
http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

2 ) Click download, select Linux platform, language and accept license and continue.

3 ) Select “Linux RPM in self-extracting file” and download jdk_filename-rpm.bin file (jdk-6u6-linux-i586-rpm.bin).

4 ) After downloaded, changed to the directory where you saved the file.

5 ) login to root user or su to root or sudo, and issue ‘chmod +x jdk_filename.-rpm.bin’ to make it executable.

```
chmod +x jdk_filename.bin
```

6 ) Execute it

```
./jdk_filename-rpm.bin
```

7 ) Press space bar , repeat until system prompt to enter yes or no, type y and enter to continue.

8 ) This will output a .rpm file in same directory

9 ) Issue `rpm -i jdk_filename.rpm`, this will install all jdk files on linux system /usr/java/jdk-version/

```
rpm -i jdk_filename.rpm
```

10 ) Create symbol links to make it execute anywhere

```
 ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/java /usr/bin/java

 ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.6.0/bin/javac /usr/bin/javac
```

11 ) type `java -version`, DONE !!

**Post-Installation Setup**
Set JAVA_HOME into environment variable

Copy following statement and append to /etc/profile or .bashrc file, make system set JAVA_HOME into system environment variable.

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0;"
```

**Install Tomcat 6 on Fedora**

```
yum install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps tomcat6-admin-webapps
```

On Fedora 13 a CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not explicitly defined following a Tomcat 6 install. It is essentially equal to /usr/share/tomcat6/ though. This threw me off when reading Tomcat 6 guides that routinely refer to a CATALINA_HOME. You could add one to your ~/.bash_profile if it helps.

```
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat6/
export CATALINA_HOME
```

Run tomcat and hope it works.

Comment: wow this is what i actually expecting !! :)
However about tomcat.... I cant use YUM repository to install it..
after trying to run yum command ... it gives output as NOTHING TO DO...
so i think i would need another way to install tomcat6 ...
Thanks alot Juned. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, on Fedora 20, it's easier. You can install both `Java` and `Tomcat` through Fedora-provided packages. Do the following being logged in as `root`:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk tomcat
```

Then, enable `Tomcat` on system startup:

```
systemctl enable tomcat
```

You can now drop a war-file into `/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/` and you are ready to go.